# Unresolved reference: app en Modulo Dinamico Android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

tengo un problema y es que estoy creando una app con Android Bundle, pero no me crea las actividades en los Módulos dinámicos, solo me da este error:

**Unresolved reference: app**

Este es el código del build.gradle del app principal:

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "bundletest.hitcel.com.bundletest"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = true
        }
        density {
            enableSplit = true
        }
        abi {
            enableSplit = true
        }
    }


    dynamicFeatures = [":Chat", ":Estadisticas"]


}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

y este el de mi módulo dinámico:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.dynamic-feature'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28



    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"


    }


}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project(':app')
}
```

Pero igual sigue sin funcionar, la inicie basado en el siguiente tutorial de Google Developers

[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/your-first-dynamic-app/index.html?index=..%2F..io2018#0)

Ni Clean project ni Build Project resuelven y todo esto queda en rojo en mi ChatActivity.tk:

```
package bundletest.hitcel.com.chat

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class ChatActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat)
    }
}
```

Esta es la estructura de mi proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Apreciaría alguna sugerencia para resolverlo. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Cuando sucedió esto fue después de una actualización de Android Studio?